# Macbook Pro Mid2012 Lags

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, upgrade, memory

I have a macbook pro mid 2012 and recently I upgraded it by changing the RAM to 16GB and HDD to 500GB SSD. It was fine for a while but now it lags a lot whenever I play any games or even when I am normally using it. I did Memory and Hard drive test and both of them were fine. I even replaced my RAM because I read it somewhere that I should replace my RAM when these things happen, but still the problem occurs.

While upgrading my Hard drive I cloned my old hard drive and then transferred that to the SSD, I don't know if that's what causing the problem.

Comment: Have you checked Activity Monitor for what might be slowing you down when this occurs?

Comment: My memory usage is around 4 GB and the CPU Load is also fine. I don't see any problem in there. Before this problem occurred I also installed XAMPP, do you think if that caused the problem?  but, I have removed it a while ago.

Comment: Strange, is it always fine even when your computer appears to slow down? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Yes and my Memory Usage is always between 3-4 GB, even if i run a big program. I don't know why that happens..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can try re-instal the osx using the: cmd+r at the start, see this video: https://youtu.be/vxSbpZAIGm8 , Isn't mine, this can help you

Comment: For some hours it was working great but now it has started again. I am tired of this..

Comment: I have readed about the RAM, i think the 16 gbs force the cpu, have you tryed with 12 gb RAM? I have the same Macbook Pro, and i have 8 gbs RAM without problems

Comment: No I have not, but my friend has the same mac as mine and even he has the 16GB RAM and his is working fine

Comment: Have you tryed the recent comment? About the trim enabler?

Comment: yes i have, still no improvement

Comment: This scares me about this mac model, i didn't see problems like this, try disabling hard drive sleep on sistem preferences, economizer.
This should help.
I'll Keep searching for this problem ;)

Comment: I also read about firmware, ssd checking and repairing permissions

Comment: Still no Improvement -_-

Comment: News ? About your mac

Comment: Be sure about the trim order, change the 16gbs RAM 1600mhz > 16gb 1333mhz, alt + cmd + p + r at restart

Comment: you want me to reset nvram?

Comment: May be your Mac is runing an error, make this before RAM change or trim order

Comment: when i do alt+cmd+p+r my mac just restarts...

Comment: Yep, have you done the trim and do this commands?

Comment: how do i change the trim order?

Comment: Should I change my SSD?

Comment: I was searching about this, i think the reason is the RAM bus, change with other Mac user with 12gbs 1600mhz or a Mac user with 16gbs 1333mhz, just a few days to test, ther's a table in apple.com with RAM supported, it says the máximum (un our case 8gb máximum or 12 - 16 gbs with 1333mhz)

Comment: Apple says that only 8 Gb Ram is supported but I talked to the Crucial guys, from where I bought my RAM and they re saying that 16GB is supported and even my friend who has the same mac as mine mid-2012 is also using 16GB of RAM and his is working good.

Comment: There is no such thing as more RAM than it supports. If the CPU was 32 bit then it would not be able to use all of your ram, it would not slow it down. Same for bus speed.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you run Yosemite or El Capitan, enable the native OS X trim support with the Terminal command : sudo trimforce enable, followed by a restart.
2. For older OS X versions try the TRIM enabler from Cindori Software.

Comment: I have tried the trimforce enable, still not happening

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning the disk, try a clean install, using a external volume.

Comment: I was going to do that but I don't have the HDD with me right now..

Answer (score 0):

I have your same hardware (macbook and ssd) and the problem was the sata cable of notebook.

For me surprise, I dont pay nothing to fix it, even my notebook is out of guarantee, there is a recall from apple for this cable.

Go you to Apple Authorized service and good lucky !